How to manage tasks with 'tags' in excel
link to document: https://schackr-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/jacobkim0707_sch_ac_kr/EcTUkDTExy5DgItlmQxq1oEB3FpTzuPbmBgMLGRktJOMag?e=8WXhLs
Hi, I'm currently trying to manage my studies with an excel document(page 2 of the linked doc.).
The problem is that i want to set a status for each lecture's 'prep' and 'WIU' (ex: haven't started, WIP, done) and set it to overall done if both is marked 'done'.
Please check out the link to the document and leave an answer if you have any ideas..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

And please include sample data in your question (if it's needed) The link to your spreadsheet will likely go dead and make the question useless to future users
